# How do I delete individual cells of a table in Indesign CC?

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud

I created a table. After filling in the data I had a couple of empty cells at end. I would like to delete those without affecting the other columns or rows. How do I do this? I looked online but they tell you how to delete the entire column or row not an individual cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete individual cells. The overall table grid must be maintained. Removing a single cell would make the table outline non-rectangular and that is not possible.

You can delete Rows or Columns by first selecting them and then using `Table > Delete` in the menu. Or, you can merge cells (combine multiple cells to look like one cell) using the `Table` menu.

Be aware, InDesign has a bug that if you try and delete the bottom row of a table the app will often crash on the Mac. I've reported this numerous times but the bug still exists. If deleting the bottom row of a table, **save** the document first.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't probably the answer you're looking for but it might get the job done:

Merge the cells and change any fills and outer stokes to none. They would effectively disappear.

I can go into more detail on this if you think it'll help.